# Getting event source instead of writing it

Tags: java, swing, jlist, valuechangelistener

Firstly : I am sorry for the question name, I could not find a good name for it .

I have the following listener

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
        if(!(arg0.getValueIsAdjusting())){
            result.setText(result.getText()+arg0.getSource().getSelectedValue().toString());//I know it is wrong!
        }
}
```

what I want to say : Is there a method that can determine the source of the event and take its value ?

it will really help it there was 15 lists for example !

or must I write a 15 condition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Call arg0.getSource() and cast it to a JList, and viola, you're there! Something like:

```
String selection = ((JList) arg0.getSource()).getSelectedValue().toString();
result.setText(result.getText() + selection);
```

Note, the aesthete in me insists on renaming that parameter to something prettier.

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lsEvent) {
  if(!(lsEvent.getValueIsAdjusting())){
     JList list = (JList) lsEvent.getSource();
     Object selection = list.getSelectedValue(); // if not using generics
     if (selection != null) {
        String stringSelection = selection.toString();
        result.setText(result.getText() + stringSelection);
     }
  }
}
```